# Relationship between universal vector bundles and principal $O(n)$ bundles?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am wondering if knowing a model for the universal principal $O(n)$ bundle would allow one to infer a corresponding model for the universal rank $n$ vector bundle, say via a balanced product construction.

I am aware of an analogous result for principal $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ bundles and would like to get a better sense of how it specializes or relates to the above question.

Comment: A model for the universal principal $O(n)$-bundle is the fibration $V_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)\rightarrow Gr_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$, where $Gr_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)\simeq BO(n)$ is the Grassmanian of $n$-planes in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ and $V_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$ is the Stiefel manifold of $n$-frames in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, which is a free, contractible right $O(n)$-space. As you point out, you may take a Borel constuction and you get the universal rank $n$ vector bundle $V_{n}(\mathbb{R}^n)\times_{O(n)}\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow Gr_n(\mathbb{R}\infty)$.

Comment: Sure thing - is there an easy way to see why the Borel construction does indeed yield the universal rank $n$ vector bundle?

Comment: There is a 1-1 correspondence between vector bundles $E$ with structure group $G$ and principal $G$-bundles $P$ over a space $X$. In one direction we form the Borel construction $P\times_G\mathbb{K}^n\cong E$, and in the other direction we declare $P=Fr(E)$ to be the frame bundle of $E$. If you are happy that $V_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)\rightarrow Gr_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$ is the universal $O(n)$-bundle then the answer to your question is immediate.

Comment: Would that be because the correspondence is natural, so that the natural isomorphism between the principal $O(n)$ bundles functor and $[-, Gr_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)]$ precomposed with the natural isomorphism between rank $n$ vector bundles and principal $O(n)$-bundles “picks out” precisely the Borel construction $V_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty) \times_{O(n)} \mathbb{R}^n$ through the Yoneda lemma?

Comment: Well, it's because the process I just described defines an equivalence of categories $Prin_G(X)\simeq Vect_G(X)$. Using the Borel construction is just one way to define this equivalence.

Comment: I see, that makes sense - thanks!